# How to create MDI form in WPF

Tags: wpf, mdi

How to create MDI form in WPF.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it so that other users with the same question can easily find it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [WPFMDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/), which is exactly wht you are looking for, and [AvalonDock](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=AvalonDock) which gives you other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Check this MDI solution for WPF .NET 4 / 4.5 on Codeplex. You can show custom user controls as windows in a container, even different type of user controls.

[MDIContainer](http://mdicontainer.codeplex.com)

Answer (score -2):

Try this, It's worked for me,

childwindow.Owner = this;